# MVVM - Binding button command does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I am working on a WPF application using the MVVM pattern. However, I am having problems with it because this is the first time I am trying to use the MVVM pattern. I have the main login view and when I press the button nothing happens I don't know why:

LoginView.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Library.View.LoginView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Library.View"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Library.ViewModel" xmlns:customcontrol="clr-namespace:Library.CustomControl"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="LoginView" Height="550" Width="800"
        WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Background="Transparent"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:LoginViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibility"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Window.Visibility>
        <Binding Path="IsViewVisible" Mode="TwoWay" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}"/>
    </Window.Visibility>
    

    
        <Border CornerRadius="12">
        <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Image/back_image.jpg" />
        </Border.Background>


        <Border CornerRadius="12"
            BorderThickness="2" 
            Opacity="0.86">

            <Border.BorderBrush>
                
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0, 0" EndPoint="1,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#462AD8" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#DA34AE" Offset="0.75"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#8A16C1" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                
            </Border.BorderBrush>

            <Border.Background>
                
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#060531" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#1B1448" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                
            </Border.Background>

            <Grid>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="ZALOGUJ SIĘ"
                               Foreground="DarkGray"
                               FontSize="10"
                               FontFamily="Montserrat"
                              Grid.Column="0"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="10,0,0,0"/>

                    <Button x:Name="btnMinimalize"
                            
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Content="-"
                            Foreground="White"
                            FontSize="16"
                            FontFamily="Montserrat"
                            Cursor="Hand"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Click="btnMinimalize_Click">
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#28AEED"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#278BEF"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                        
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Border Width="18" Height="18"
                                        CornerRadius="9"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                        
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="btnClosed"   
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Content="X"
                            Foreground="White"
                            FontSize="12"
                            FontFamily="Montserrat"
                            Cursor="Hand"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Click="btnClosed_Click">
                        
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#DA34AE"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#C62DAE"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>

                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Border Width="18" Height="18"
                                        CornerRadius="9"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>

                <StackPanel Width="250"
                            Grid.Row="2"
                            Orientation="Vertical"
                            Margin="0,35,0,0">
                    <Image Source="/Image/Logo_image.jpg" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Biblioteka Narodowa"
                               Foreground="White"
                               FontSize="25"
                               FontWeight="Medium"
                               FontFamily="Montserrat"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    
                    <TextBlock Text="Nazwa użytkownika"
                               Foreground="DarkGray"
                               FontSize="12"
                               FontWeight="Medium"
                               FontFamily="Montserrat"
                               Margin="0,35,0,0"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="txtUser"
                             Text="{Binding Username,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                             FontSize="13"
                             FontWeight="Medium"
                             FontFamily="Montserrat"
                             Foreground="White"
                             CaretBrush="LightGray"
                             BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                             BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
                             Height="28"
                             VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                             Margin="0,5,0,0"
                             Padding="25,0,0,0">
                        
                        <TextBox.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Image/user-solid.png" Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentX="Left">
                            </ImageBrush>
                        </TextBox.Background>
                        
                    </TextBox>

                    <TextBlock Text="Hasło"
                               Foreground="DarkGray"
                               FontSize="12"
                               FontWeight="Medium"
                               FontFamily="Montserrat"
                               Margin="0,15,0,0"/>

                    <customcontrol:BindablePassword Password="{Binding Password,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                    Height="28"
                                                    Margin="0,5,0,0">
                        
                    </customcontrol:BindablePassword>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorMessage}"
                               Foreground="#D7596D"
                               FontSize="12"
                               FontWeight="Medium"
                               FontFamily="Montserrat"
                               Margin="0,15,0,0"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

                    <Button x:Name="btnLogin"   
                            Command="{Binding LoginComand}"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Content="Zaloguj"
                            Foreground="White"
                            FontSize="12"
                            FontFamily="Montserrat"
                            Cursor="Hand"
                            Margin="0,30,0,0" >

                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#462AD8"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#28AEED"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>

                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Border Width="150" Height="40"
                                        CornerRadius="9"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Margin="0,15,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Zapomniałeś Hasła?"
                               Foreground="DarkGray"
                               FontSize="12"
                               FontWeight="Medium"
                               FontFamily="Montserrat"/>
                    
                    <TextBlock Text="Reset"
                               Foreground="DarkGray"
                               FontSize="12"
                               FontWeight="Medium"
                               FontFamily="Montserrat"
                               Cursor="Hand"
                               Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Border>


</Window>
```

loginViewModel.cs

```
using Library.Model;
using Library.Repositories;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Library.ViewModel
{
    public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        //Feilds
        private string _username;
        private SecureString _password;
        private string _errorMessage;
        private bool _isViewVisible=true;

        private IUserRepository userRepository;

        public string Username
        {
            get
            {
                return _username;
            }
            set
            {
                _username = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Username));
            }
        }
        public SecureString Password 
        {
            get
            {
                return _password;
            }
            set
            {
                _password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Password));   
            }
        }
        public string ErrorMessage { 
            get
            {
                return _errorMessage;
            }
            set
            {
                _errorMessage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ErrorMessage));
            } 
        }
        public bool IsViewVisible 
        { 
            get
            {
                return _isViewVisible;  
            }
            set
            {
                _isViewVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsViewVisible));
            } 
        }

        //->Commands
        public ICommand LoginComand { get;  }
        public ICommand RecoverPasswordCommand { get;  }
        public ICommand ShowPasswordCommand { get;  }
        public ICommand RememberPasswordCommand { get;  }



        //Constructor
        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            userRepository= new UserRepository();
            LoginComand = new ViewModelCommand(ExecuteLoginCommand, CanExecuteLoginCommand);
            RecoverPasswordCommand = new ViewModelCommand(p=>ExecuteRecoverPassCommand("",""));
        }



        private bool CanExecuteLoginCommand(object obj)
        {
            bool vaildDate;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Username) || Username.Length < 3 || Password == null ||
                Password.Length < 3)
                vaildDate = false;
            else 
                vaildDate = true;
            return vaildDate;
        }

        private void ExecuteLoginCommand(object obj)
        {

            var isValidUser = userRepository.AuthenticateUser(new NetworkCredential(Username, Password));
            if (isValidUser)
            {
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(
                    new GenericIdentity(Username), null);
              isValidUser= false;
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorMessage = "* Błąd w nazwie użtkownika lub błędne hasło";
            }
        }

        private void ExecuteRecoverPassCommand(string username,string email)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelbase.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Library.ViewModel
{
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        { 
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelCommand.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Library.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModelCommand : ICommand
    {
        //Feilds
        private readonly Action<object> _executeAction;
        private readonly Predicate<object>? _canExecuteAction;

        //Constructos
        public ViewModelCommand(Action<object> executeAction)
        {
            _executeAction = executeAction;
            _canExecuteAction = null;
        }

        public ViewModelCommand(Action<object> executeAction, Predicate<object> canExecuteAction)
        {
            _executeAction = executeAction;
            _canExecuteAction = canExecuteAction;
        }

        //Events
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;}
        }

        //Methods
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecuteAction == null ? true : _canExecuteAction(parameter);

        public void Execute(object parameter) => _executeAction(parameter);
    }
}
```

I checked the code to see if something is missing, I have adjusted the DataContext because when I checked it, everything went through, no error is shown even when connecting to the database everything works.I changed in App.xaml the call of my first window and it works on the sub-condition.

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Library.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Library"
             Startup="ApplicationStart">
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using Library.View;


namespace Library
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected void ApplicationStart(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var loginView= new LoginView();
            loginView.Show();
            loginView.IsVisibleChanged += (s, ev) =>
            {
                if (loginView.IsVisible == false && loginView.IsLoaded)
                {
                    var mainView = new MainWindow();
                    mainView.Show();
                    loginView.Close();
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend the community toolkit mvvm.  Nuget package.  Save you re inventing everything with the risk you get it wrong. Also saves typing code because of the code generator.

Comment: You misspelled Command="{Binding LoginComand}" -> LoginCommand

Comment: thanks kevin however correcting the name did not help :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal example demonstrating commands and canexecutechanged using the community toolkit mvvm.

My mainwindow:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding UserName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button Content="Login"
                Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Viewmodel

```
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(LoginCommand))]
    private string userName = string.Empty;

    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(IsLoginExecutable))]
    private void Login()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello from Login");
    }
    private bool IsLoginExecutable() 
    { 
        return userName.Length > 3; 
    }
}
```

When run, the button is initially disabled and greyed.

[image]

As I type the 4th letter, the button is enabled:

[image]

The attributes are largely self explanatory.
But...

There is a partial class generated by a code generator.

That creates the public properties for the private variables.

The notifycanexecutechanged attribute will raise canexecutechanged as each character is typed and transfers to the viewmodel username.

The canexecute part of the relaycommand attribute sets up the IsLoginExecutable bool. Which is of course called as each character is typed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/

https://blogs.msmvps.com/bsonnino/2022/08/06/the-mvvm-pattern-revisited-with-the-mvvm-community-toolkit-8-0/

Answer (score 0):

Use mvvm community toolkit 8.0 you can easly do mvvm architecture without headache.
for reference :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVIzK2snugk